# Peter flew a kite this week

Tags: tense

Are these sentences correct?

> Peter flew a kite today.
>
> Peter flew a kite this week.
>
> Peter flew a kite this morning.

Comments: If Peter flew a kite in the morning, I think in the evening or late afternoon I can say "Peter flew a kite this morning" or "Peter flew a kite today". It is past. But if Peter flew a kite on Monday and Tuesday, I on Thursday say "Peter flew a kite this week", I feel it odd. I think It should be "Peter flew a kite on Monday and Tuesday". Or "Peter has flown a kite this week". Or "Peter is flying a kite", which can imply Peter will fly a kite later in this week.

Comment: What's the difference? Past is past, whether a picosecond or a gigayear.

Comment: Your sentences are correct if they are elliptical ones, with "earlier" implied after the word "kite". Otherwise they are somehow weird and wanting perfect.

Comment: Do you mean I should add "earlier“ to all the three sentences?

Comment: If you add 'earlier', that will make those sentences grammatically correct.

Comment: "Earlier today" means at earlier time of today. "Earlier this morning" means at earlier time of this morning. "Earlier this week" means at earlier time of this week. If we are in the afternoon, do we have to say "Peter flew a kite earlier this morning"? I think "Peter flew a kite this morning" is fine. Actually if Peter flew a kite after 11:00 in the morning, you can't say "Peter flew a kite earlier this morning".

Comment: Your three sentences are perfectly OK. If he flew it a couple of times earlier this week we would say, "Peter's been flying a kite this week." In everyday conversation even that is a bit abrupt. "Peter's been out flying his kite a couple of times this week," would be more colloquial.

Comment: Yes. "Peter flew a kite this morning" is fine. All your reasoning is correct. ALL of it! :-)

Comment: If Peter flew a kite only on Monday, can you say "Peter flew a kite this week" on Thursday?

Answer (score 2):

Situation: Peter's boss tells him, "Go fly a kite! And you had better get it done by the end of next week. If you don't, you're fired!
The end of next week has arrived. The boss says to the secretary, "I'm firing Peter today because he hasn't flown a kite all week!" The secretary responds, "But... **Peter flew a kite this week.** I took a picture on my cell phone for you to see."

Comment: Isn't it better to say "But...Peter has flown a kite this week"?